# Setting and removing cookies with jQuery cookie doesn't reflect in Chrome inspector

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I am using jQuery cookie and I cannot seem to add a cookie with:

```
$.cookie('foo', 'bar');
```

nor

```
$.cookie('foo', 'bar', { path:'/' });
```

nor can I seem to remove a cookie that was created via response header with.

```
$.removeCookie('foo', { path:'/path-matches-one-set-via-server' });
```

I have tried right clicking and clicking refresh and have tried clicking the refresh icon but it isn't updating.

Comment: What you have should work fine. Have you added the cookie plugin successfully? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, no errors. Yes i've added successfully. I've just realised that locally is working fine (non https) whereas in qa stag prod environments (https) it isn't working. The script is definitely there. It autocompletes $.cook... when I type in the console. Could the https have something to do with it?